# Monte Carlo Methods for Pricing Derivatives

Tags: monte-carlo, simulations, quantitative

can someone please suggest a good book on Monte Carlo Simulation for Pricing Derivatives?

Don't want a book which is too complicated like a PhD level. A Masters level should be good.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

This is the book from a masters degree.

http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~bianchi/athens/Proba_Num_11-12.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Glasserman's book is the book I would recommend on Monte Carlo methods as well.

Comment: But it's complicated

Comment: I can help you. If there is something

Comment: Student T - Why do you think its complicated?